# Mapping an array of objects and grouping by key in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

How can I succinctly achieve the following manipulation in javascript:

```
[ {key:'a', value:1}, {key:'a', value:2}, {key:'b', value:4} ]
```

->

```
{'a':[1,2], 'b':[4] }
```

Code simplicity is what I'm really going for and I am already using lodash but I couldn't really figure out how to do this manipulation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `reduce`:

```js
var arr = [ {key:'a', value:1}, {key:'a', value:2}, {key:'b', value:4} ];

var obj = arr.reduce(function(acc, x) {
    if (!acc[x.key]) acc[x.key] = [];
    acc[x.key].push(x.value);
    return acc;
}, {});

document.write(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

See [MDN docs on `reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for more information.

If you have to support IE8 or below (which doesn't have `reduce`), you could use [a polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Polyfill), or you could manually loop over the array and set object keys as you go (which would look uglier). It looks like [lodash also already has a `reduce` function, too](https://lodash.com/docs#reduce).